# Solve this interview question: Letter Soup (JS)

Tags: javascript, algorithm

This is an interview question that I could not solve yet... I have this matrix:

```
[
 ['A', 'B', 'R'],
 ['H', 'A', 'H'],
 ['A', 'P', 'R'],
 ['P', 'L', 'A'],
 ['G', 'E', 'F']
]
```

I need to find the word "APPLE", but the letters that I can choose must be closest as possible, in this case: (2;0) (2;1) (3;0) (3;1) (4;1)

I must find the word and return the coordinates of its characters

Using Javascript how do you manage to do it?

I Tried this:

```js
const soup = [
 ['A', 'B', 'R'],
 ['H', 'A', 'H'],
 ['A', 'P', 'R'],
 ['P', 'L', 'A'],
 ['G', 'E', 'F']
];

const word = 'APPLE';
const letters = word.split('');
let hashTable = {};

for (let letter of letters) {
  for (let line = 0; line < soup.length; line++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < soup[line].length; i++ ) {
      console.log(soup[line][i]);
      if (letter === soup[line][i]) {
       hashTable[letter] = [line, i];
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(hashTable);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of *your own* attempt, together with a description of the problems you have with it and what debugging you have tried.

Comment: Well. I tried to save the chars in a Hashtable (object) and save there the coordinates.
But I have problems when the chars are repeated and I need to start again

Comment: I added my code in the first post.

Comment: How is "closest" defined? Why is 2,0 better than 1,1 for the "A"?

Comment: That was the requirement, I cannot take a random letter.

Comment: How is that requirement formulated? I mean the A at 1,1 is just as close to the P, as the A at 2,0. So what is the requirement saying by which you cannot start with 1,1? Can't there be multiple, equivalent solutions?

Comment: Sure, it must be solved horizontally only. So you don't have the complexity to look in each direction.

Comment: What do you mean "horizontally only". In the example you are making connections that are vertical and diagonal too. Please provide the full description of the question. Right now it is unclear what is required.

Comment: You need to search the word, looking for the right or left of each character.

Comment: This seems to be something of a [traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Comment: So if the distance scoring goes "left-to-right" then "top-to-bottom", I think it should be pretty easy. I haven't tried it, but it seems like you'd just search the matrix in that order, and reduce it down to all letters (with coordinates) that are in the word. Once you have that list, and now that you know it's in order, it should be a fairly simple matter of figuring out which set of letters that form the word are most tightly grouped.

Comment: You're hardly answering the questions here... I am voting to close this question.

Comment: This could be a solution @slappy I Will try.

Comment: The thing is... you have to, if any, start with the characters those exist most frequently. In this particular case the priority is 'P'. Find required many (2 in this case) 'P's those are closest. Make this closest group of 'P's a line (if there are only 2 'P's required) or an area (if there are 3+ 'P's in your sentence) and then start checking with the next most frequent character and repeat what you did before by checking the distance to the line or area obtained in the previous stage.

Answer (score 2):

You can use matrix row and columns as key and use the alphabet as the value. as in your case you are storing p two times in the same object. so we cannot duplicate keys in object use below code for your reference

```js
const soup = [
  ["A", "B", "R"],
  ["H", "A", "H"],
  ["A", "P", "R"],
  ["P", "L", "A"],
  ["G", "E", "F"]
];

const word = "APPLE";
let index = 0;
let hashTable = {};

for (let line = 0; line < soup.length; line++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < soup[line].length; i++) {
    if (word[index] === soup[line][i] && index < word.length) {
      const col = i + 1;
      const row =  line + 1
      const key = row + "," + col;
      hashTable[key] = soup[line][i];
      index++;
    }
  }
}

console.log(hashTable);
```

Comment: This just finds the letters of the `"APPLE"` in the order it appears in the matrix. `A` is taken from the first row. The letter aren't even *connected* to each other in the matrix

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't even really begin to do what the question describes.